# ionic validation with custom validation function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I can validate form by the help of FormBuilder and FormControl like below

```
this.pricePerHour = false/true; //based on visible or not

this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      PerHour: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([this.PriceValidator(this.pricePerHour)]))
     //this.pricePerHour is a boolean variable, initially false
    });


priceValidator(argPerHour: boolean): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      console.log(argPerHour); 
     // always false even on true
      if (control.value == '' && argPerHour == true) {
        return { valid: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
    }
```

**Here I want to validate PerHour only if pricePerHour is true.**

In this case form is checking **PerHour** field either **pricePerHour** is false or true (visible/disable).
Means boolean variable **pricePerHour** is always false inside **priceValidator()**.

I also check with below but did not work:-

```
   this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   Description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   PerHour: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([this.pricePerHour ==    
     true ? null : Validators.required]))
   });
```

Any suggestion on this.

Comment: at the time of initialization `yourBool ?  PerHour: new FormControl('',Validators.required)) : null`

Comment: Ok fine, I will check now

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, How can I use this with above code. Because this.bool will give an error inside above code.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, I use the same at the time of initialization but it's value not reflecting on value(PerHour) change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was so simple and I made this so complex.
I just add below lines where I was calling change function. Solved :slight_smile:

```
this.myForm.get('PerHour').clearValidators();
this.myForm.get('PerHour').setValidators([Validators.required]);
this.myForm.get('PerHour').updateValueAndValidity();
```